# issue with making a AJAX API call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making the below API call via AJAX

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://xxxxxxxxxx",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"api_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "attributes" : [{"external_id" : "3610", "quality_score" : "2"}]
                          },
                    dataType:'application/json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(error){
                        console.log("Something went wrong", error);
                    }
                });
        }
```

in return I'm getting the below error

```
responseText: "{"message":"'attributes' must be an array"}"
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: How it looks on your serverside? What your are returning to "message"?

Comment: is that an external api? otherwise please include relevant server side code

Comment: I'm trying to post to a 3rd party service. When I use the postman with the same json no problem. not sure why it's giving me this array error when used via ajax.

Comment: Link to the 3rd party service docs. Also, console log you attribute before you send, you might not be sending what you think you're sending.

Comment: Hi TJBlackman. How can I check the log of data been sent?